# Unity adding multiple enemy from a same prefab but the others doesn't working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

When i duplicate enemy the clone one is moving once and stopping on the same point but the original one moving and make actions

[video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12C9bAMxisWnn3UwymkGOrNAqc1yTpNjg/view?usp=sharing)

I'm trying to make a dungeon game but I'm stuck on this thing since 4 days. I need to put multiple enemies, the first one working but the others doesn't

This is enemy script that have enemy movement, stats, etc.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float health = 3;

    [Header("combat")]
    [SerializeField] float attackCD = 3f;
    [SerializeField] float attackRange = 1f;
    [SerializeField] float aggroRange = 4f;







    GameObject player;
    NavMeshAgent agent;
    Animator anim;
    float timePassed;
    float newDestinationCD = 0.5f;


    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

   void Update()
    {
        anim.SetFloat("speed", agent.velocity.magnitude / agent.speed);

        if (timePassed >= attackCD)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, transform.position) <= attackRange)
            {
                anim.SetTrigger("attack");
                GetComponentInChildren<enemyDamageDealer>().StartDealDamage();
                timePassed = 0;
            }
        }
        timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

        if (newDestinationCD <= 0 && Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, transform.position) <= aggroRange)
        {
            newDestinationCD = 0.5f;
            agent.SetDestination(player.transform.position);
        }
        newDestinationCD -= Time.deltaTime;
        transform.LookAt(player.transform);
    }

    void Die()
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    public void TakeDamage(float damageAmount)
    {
        health -= damageAmount;
        anim.SetTrigger("damage");
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    public void startDealDamage()
    {
        GetComponentInChildren<enemyDamageDealer>().StartDealDamage();
    }

    public void endDealDamage()
    {
        GetComponentInChildren<enemyDamageDealer>().EndDealDamage();
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, attackRange);
        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, aggroRange);
    }

}
```

This is the enemyDamageDealer script that have enemy attacking to player when it close

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemyDamageDealer : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool canDealDamage;
    bool hasDealtDamage;

    [SerializeField] float weaponLenght;
    [SerializeField] float weaponDamage;
    

    void Start()
    {
        canDealDamage = false;
        hasDealtDamage = false;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (canDealDamage && !hasDealtDamage)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;

            int layerMask = 1 << 8;
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out hit, weaponLenght, layerMask))
            {
                if (hit.transform.TryGetComponent(out playerStats player))
                {
                    player.TakeDamage(weaponDamage);
                    print("düşman vurdu");
                    hasDealtDamage = true;
                }
                
            }
        }
    }

    public void StartDealDamage()
    {
        canDealDamage = true;
        hasDealtDamage = false;
    }

    public void EndDealDamage()
    {
        canDealDamage = false;
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position - transform.up * weaponLenght);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to debug it to see whtts going on

Comment: Understanding how Unity's NavMesh system works is fundamental. Make sure to properly configure your NavMeshAgent and bake the NavMesh for all instances and you'll be good.

Comment: Does the error persist if you make a copy (`ctrl+d`) of the working enemy?

Comment: yes, the error persist when i copy(ctrl+d) of working enemy

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using NavMesh Surface, I was doing it from a video published 1 year ago. My understanding is that unity has made a few changes in NavMesh in this 1 year.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).